# VirtualObjectListView - Binding data from Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, objectlistview

I spent hours (newbie) trying to load data from simple ms access database into VirtualObjectListView... I keep trying but no luck. I've tried to load same data into DataGridView and it worked. But I have little over 3 million rows in Access database to display...

VB.NET; please help guys.

Sample table: users (userid, username, password)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some of the code you've tried?

Comment: @Eraph: Hi, thank you for your time. Unfortunately, there isn't much to tell. Can't even add dictionary object or even a single item to the ObjectListView control :( I've been using regular ListView control often but never ObjectListView... The only thing I was able to do was to add columns but via designer not via code :( I wish to at least add few sample rows in the blank ObjectListView control on my form :( Thanks!

Comment: Please, please, please read the Getting Started section of the ObjectListView website, http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html, especially the "Unlearn you must" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FastDataListView` instead of `VirtualObjectListView`.

Set `DataSource` and `DataMember` as you did for the DataGridView.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the question here(http://tinyurl.com/pxta8p8) Thanks in advance.